# Is there any way to decorate a class such that the resulting class's supertypes are known to the typechecker?

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-typing

I'd like to be able to write a class decorator that returns classes of a given base type `B` regardless of the input class, such that I can then use the decorated classes as objects of type `B`.

I've done something like this:

```
T = TypeVar("T")

class Base:
    pass

def decorate_class(cls: Type[T]) -> Type[Base]:
    class Ret(Base, cls):
        pass

    return Ret

@decorate_class
class C:
    pass

def takes_base(inst: Type[Base]) -> Type[Base]:
    return inst

takes_base(C)
```

but pyre complains that in the call to `takes_base`, it expected an argument of `Type[Base]` but instead got `Type[C]`, despite the return type of the decorator.

Comment: "a class decorator that returns classes of a given base type B regardless of the input class" - why is applying this decorator to `C` any easier or more practical than just adding `B` to its bases explicitly?

Comment: So, I think `mypy` currently has [a bug](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14458) that breaks when you try to use a paramter as a base class, but FWIW, if I change `cls: Type[T]` to `cls: Type[object]` since this function cannot be generic like that) then pyright correctly infers the type of `C` as `type[Base]`.